# adding max_cols to individual widgets using gridster

Tags: jquery, widget

I want to limit the resizing of widgets depending upon the type of widget. 
Ex: I have a 'information widget' that can scale upto max 50% of the total gridContainer and another widget 'graph' can scale upto 100% of the container.
below is the initialization of the gridster :

```
gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({

        widget_base_dimensions: [baseWidth, baseWidth],
        widget_margins: [4, 20],
        max_cols:[4],

        resize: {
            enabled: true,
            max_size:[2],
            min_size:[1],
            stop: function(e, ui, $widget) {

                var s = gridster.serialize();
                console.log(JSON.stringify(s));
        }
        }

    }).data('gridster');
```

I'm using `max_size:[2]` for limiting the resize. However this gets applied to all the widgets. below is the json of my widgets:

```
 var serialize = [
    {
        "widgetId": "0",
        "text": "Test Info",
        "description": "",
        "type": "info",

         "path":"test-info.png",
        "dataType": "TEST_INFO",
        "position": {

            "col": 1,
            "row": 1,
            "size_x": 1,
            "size_y": 2

        }
    },
    {
        "widgetId": "1",
        "title": "Test Details",
        "description": "",
        "type": "info",
        "path":"test-details.png",
        "dataType": "TEST_DETAILS",
        "position": {
            "col": 2,
            "row": 1,
            "size_x": 2,
            "size_y": 2
        }
    },
    {

     "widgetId": "2",
     "title": "Test Stats",
     "description": "",
     "type": "info",
     "path":"test-stats.png",
    "dataType": "TEST_STATS",
    "position": {
            "col": 4,
            "row": 1,
            "size_x": 1,
            "size_y": 2
               }
},
    {
        "widgetId": "widget_3",
        "title": "Test Plan",
        "description": "",
        "type": "line",
        "dataType": "TEST_PLAN",
        "path":"test-plan.png",
        "position": {
            "col": 1,
            "row": 3,
            "size_x": 2,
            "size_y": 2
        }


    }];
```

so for the first 2 widgets, i need the widgets to scale upto 50% and for the remaining ones, i need them to scale upto 100%? How can i achieve this?

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is a year later.. Hope the below can help in some way to anyone else!

Instead of using a global max_size for all of the widgets, I would suggest applying these limits via HTML when you are building them up in the first place.

Using `data-max-sizex` and `data-max-sizex` could help in this instance, as you can define a maximum for each individual widget.

[Demo on resize limits](http://gridster.net/demos/resize-limits.html)

E.g : `<li id="0" data-max-sizey="6" data-max-sizex="2" data-sizey="2" data-sizex="1" data-col="1" data-row="1">Test info</li>`

Hope this helps!